# I have an issue where if my child dag is dependent on multiple parent dags

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am facing an issue with the child dag dependent on multiple parent dags.

Dags A, B and C are my parent dags. 
Dag D is my child dag.

- Dag A has tasks     -->     A1,A2
- Dag B has tasks     -->     B1,B2
- Dag C has tasks     -->     C1,C2

The child dag D should run after successful execution of the following parent tasks:

- A1,
- B2,
- C2

How to achieve that? Any suggestion are appreciated. Thanks in advance.